# Adjust ggplot in RMarkdown

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown, font-family

I am trying to add a plot in an `RMardkwon` document, yet when I compile the PDF the graph is cut.

How can I adjust the `size` and the `font family` so it matches my Rmarkdown?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried playing with values of `+ theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))` in the code and then playing with chunk options `fig.width =` and `fig.height =`

Comment: Additionally to adding a margin to the right, you might need to turn clipping off with `+coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size using

```
my_plot +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

Replace `20` with the desired font size.

You can change the font family using

```
my_plot +
  theme(text = element_text(family="Times"))
```

Replace `Times` with the desired font family.